# Issue with Spring fox when downgrading version to Spring 3.2.9

Tags: rest, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I was wondering if it is possible to run Spring fox on Spring 3.2.9.RELEASE.

What I have done so far is setup the implementation on Spring.4.1.1, and it works great I can see my documentation.
But, not sure what is wrong when I do the same on Spring 3.2.9.RELEASE (Spring 3.2.9 is a need for me as the project do not want to upgrade to higher version)

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.swagger</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringRestfulWebServicesWithJSONExample</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SpringRestfulWebServicesWithJSONExample Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>   
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
             <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>SpringRestfulWebServicesWithJSONExample</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.2.9.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'apiDocumentationScanner' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/subash_prakash/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.2.2/springfox-spring-web-2.2.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/scanners/ApiDocumentationScanner.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.ApiListingScanner]: : Error creating bean with name 'apiListingScanner' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/subash_prakash/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.2.2/springfox-spring-web-2.2.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/scanners/ApiListingScanner.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.ApiDescriptionReader]: : Error creating bean with name 'apiDescriptionReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/subash_prakash/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.2.2/springfox-spring-web-2.2.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/scanners/ApiDescriptionReader.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [springfox.documentation.spring.web.readers.operation.ApiOperationReader]: : Error creating bean with name 'apiOperationReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/subash_prakash/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.2.2/springfox-spring-web-2.2.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/readers/operation/ApiOperationReader.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class springfox.documentation.spring.web.readers.operation.ApiOperationReader]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'apiOperationReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/subash_prakash/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.2.2/springfox-spring-web-2.2.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/readers/operation/ApiOperationReader.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class springfox.documentation.spring.web.readers.operation.ApiOperationReader]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'apiDescriptionReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/subash_prakash/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.2.2/springfox-spring-web-2.2.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/scanners/ApiDescriptionReader.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [springfox.documentation.spring.web.readers.operation.ApiOperationReader]: : Error creating bean with name 'apiOperationReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/subash_prakash/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.2.2/springfox-spring-web-2.2.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/readers/operation/ApiOperationReader.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class springfox.documentation.spring.web.readers.operation.ApiOperationReader]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'apiOperationReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/subash_prakash/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.2.2/springfox-spring-web-2.2.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/readers/operation/ApiOperationReader.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class springfox.documentation.spring.web.readers.operation.ApiOperationReader]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'apiListingScanner' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/subash_prakash/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.2.2/springfox-spring-web-2.2.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/scanners/ApiListingScanner.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.ApiDescriptionReader]: : Error creating bean with name 'apiDescriptionReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/subash_prakash/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.2.2/springfox-spring-web-2.2.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/scanners/ApiDescriptionReader.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [springfox.documentation.spring.web.readers.operation.ApiOperationReader]: : Error creating bean with name 'apiOperationReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/subash_prakash/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.2.2/springfox-spring-web-2.2.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/readers/operation/ApiOperationReader.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class springfox.documentation.spring.web.readers.operation.ApiOperationReader]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'apiOperationReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/subash_prakash/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.2.2/springfox-spring-web-2.2.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/readers/operation/ApiOperationReader.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class springfox.documentation.spring.web.readers.operation.ApiOperationReader]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'apiDescriptionReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/subash_prakash/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.2.2/springfox-spring-web-2.2.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/scanners/ApiDescriptionReader.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [springfox.documentation.spring.web.readers.operation.ApiOperationReader]: : Error creating bean with name 'apiOperationReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/subash_prakash/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.2.2/springfox-spring-web-2.2.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/readers/operation/ApiOperationReader.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class springfox.documentation.spring.web.readers.operation.ApiOperationReader]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'apiOperationReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/subash_prakash/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.2.2/springfox-spring-web-2.2.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/readers/operation/ApiOperationReader.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class springfox.documentation.spring.web.readers.operation.ApiOperationReader]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:752)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1075)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:979)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:917)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:860)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:817)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:745)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1075)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:979)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.getApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:170)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:86)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.ObjectMapperConfigurer.fireObjectMapperConfiguredEvent(ObjectMapperConfigurer.java:88)
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.ObjectMapperConfigurer.configureMessageConverters(ObjectMapperConfigurer.java:66)
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.ObjectMapperConfigurer.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ObjectMapperConfigurer.java:47)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1505)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:633)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:602)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:521)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:462)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:532)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.embedded.JettyEmbeddedAdapter.start(JettyEmbeddedAdapter.java:67)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.common.AbstractJettyLauncherMain.launch(AbstractJettyLauncherMain.java:84)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.embedded.JettyEmbeddedLauncherMain.main(JettyEmbeddedLauncherMain.java:42)
Caused by: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'apiListingScanner' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/subash_prakash/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.2.2/springfox-spring-web-2.2.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/scanners/ApiListingScanner.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.ApiDescriptionReader]: : Error creating bean with name 'apiDescriptionReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/subash_prakash/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.2.2/springfox-spring-web-2.2.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/scanners/ApiDescriptionReader.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [springfox.documentation.spring.web.readers.operation.ApiOperationReader]: : Error creating bean with name 'apiOperationReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/subash_prakash/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.2.2/springfox-spring-web-2.2.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/readers/operation/ApiOperationReader.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class springfox.documentation.spring.web.readers.operation.ApiOperationReader]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'apiOperationReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/subash_prakash/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.2.2/springfox-spring-web-2.2.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/readers/operation/ApiOperationReader.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class springfox.documentation.spring.web.readers.operation.ApiOperationReader]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'apiDescriptionReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/subash_prakash/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.2.2/springfox-spring-web-2.2.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/scanners/ApiDescriptionReader.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [springfox.documentation.spring.web.readers.operation.ApiOperationReader]: : Error creating bean with name 'apiOperationReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/subash_prakash/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.2.2/springfox-spring-web-2.2.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/readers/operation/ApiOperationReader.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class springfox.documentation.spring.web.readers.operation.ApiOperationReader]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'apiOperationReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/subash_prakash/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.2.2/springfox-spring-web-2.2.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/readers/operation/ApiOperationReader.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class springfox.documentation.spring.web.readers.operation.ApiOperationReader]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:752)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1075)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:979)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:917)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:860)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:817)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:745)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1075)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:979)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at ...
```

The above error only occurs when I am on Spring-3.2.9 and not on Spring 4.X version.

Need Help to generate docs using Spring-3.2.9

Comment: If you use springfox version 2.4.0 on both your dependencies it should work with spring 3.x

Comment: Thanks @DilipKrishnan.
I think this should be the answer as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between 2.0 and 2.3 we unfortunately broke compatibility with 3.2+. Since then we've worked pretty hard to restore support for spring 3.2.x.

If you use springfox version 2.4.0 on both your dependencies it should work with spring 3.x

Comment: I was just looking into the git changes and wanted to know if 3.2.9-Release is supported with springfox-2.6.0

Comment: @coldy it should be. If not please create an issue